# Youtube videos not working on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: youtube, codecs

Hey i installed ubuntu a few days ago and i have a problem, when i turn on my computer and open youtube, the videos play normally but after a few hours on the computer i can't see any more videos because they don't play, it's not my internet because i can surf normally in other applications, when this happens i have to restart the computer to be able to see videos but after a few hours the same problem occurs, i already have ubuntu codecs use this command: sudo apt-get remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg, the terminal gives me He said this once run the command: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra is already the newest version (1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1).
chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra set to manually installed. I also tried deleting youtube cookies but nothing, I saw some videos of people saying that it was the date of the computer but I have it updated.